# Верно сохранять/извлекать данные в/из браузера

Tags: браузер, blazor, storage, webassembly, blazor-client-side

[Blazor School](https://blazorschool.com/) предлагает различные способы хранения данных, чтоб пользователь мог сохранять информацию (логин, возможные другие настройки...)

- [CacheStorage](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/cache-storage-658620)
- [CookieStorage](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/cookie-storage-459520)
- [IndexedDbStorage](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/indexeddb-storage-749869)
- [LocalStorage](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/local-storage-926535)
- [MemoryStorage](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/memory-storage-421887)
- [SessionStorage](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/session-storage-705060)

[скачав проект урока](https://github.com/Blazor-School/browser-storage-blazor-wasm-dotnet6) его можно потестировать, но для меня все эти способы как-то схожи. Все сохраняют в браузере, и когда читаешь их документацию, мало, что отличается...*(создайте класс, добавьте функции, сохраняет ключ/значение)*

Подскажите, какое решение для чего подходит (что-то для логина, что-то для цвета кнопки, а что то для последней сессии например, чтоб показать имя пользователя...), Кто работал на Блазор Веб Ассембли **поделитесь опытом**

[вот мой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508765/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5), сейчас немного больше информации, но все равно необходима помощь профессионала.

Comment: что значит _Все сохраняют в навигаторе_?

Comment: Проекты, сохраняют в навигаторе ,если скачать то непонятно какая там разница. Среди них

Comment: Все они.......они схожи.....блазор объясняет типа сохранения в навигаторе данных. И там кстати пишется,что куки устарело...потом когда скачиваешь с гитхаба, видишь что 6 типов аж. Какой выбрать, какой для чего

Comment: это обертки над браузерным api, смотри [web storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) и т.д. Но описание есть и по ссылкам, которые приведены в вопросе

Comment: ок, Сессион по названию говорит, что временное(но как будто все равно еще понять бы и услышать если кто уже ну делал же в своем проекте, что использовал), а `IndexedDbStorage` чем от куки отличается тут вообще не оч ясно ?

Comment: [However, in 2023, Cookies will be bound to a domain......](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/cookie-storage-459520) а раньше как было не к домену присвоенны куки были что ли? и почему пишут *Cookie storage is a legacy technique to keep track ....* //и можно ли их в миксе использовать, чем чревато

Comment: читай описание на mdn сначала.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146528/discussion-between-dev18-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для хранения всевозможных персональных настроек используйте бэк-энд приложения.

Гораздо реже, если вы хотите запомнить что-то специфичное для UI, например у вас можно менять  ширину сайдбара, то LocalStorage хороший выбор. Важно помнить, что там не должно быть ни какой секретной\полусекретной информации. Хотя бы потому что если зайдёт другой пользователь, он получит доступ к этим настройкам. Но в 99,9% случаев из одного браузера не заходят разные пользователи.

Что ещё реально может пригодится, это MemoryStorage, т.е. то что хранится только пока не сброшена память вкладки браузера. Но не в таком виде, как по вашей ссылке. Там он сделан как подобие LocalStorage, SessionStorage, т.е. глобальная свалка ключ-значение на основе Dictionary<string, string> внутри самого блейзера. Это сделано специально, чтобы показать что если очень надо можно вот так спародировать (*)Storage. Но это мало кому нужно будет на самом деле. Просто создайте синглтон, который будет хранить, то что вам нужно в том виде как вам нужно, и имеет интерфейс такой какой вам нужен.

Куки нужны только тогда, когда имеет смысл шарить что-то с сервером, причём на каждый запрос. Естественно это нужно редко. Ещё реже нужно создавать или читать их на стороне браузера. У меня было приложение на Blazor, где была кука для аутентификации, но Blazor никогда её не трогал, а сервер с её помощью проверял что за пользователь к нему обращается. Ещё это может быть сессионная кука, в том числе для незарегистрированных пользователей, но в моей практике и она создавалась на сервере.

Иногда используют иную схему аутентификации при которой сервер отдаёт токен в браузер явно и принимает через какой-нибудь заголовок запроса. В таком случае это уже дело Blazor где хранить этот токен. Как правило токен зашифрован, а не зашифрованная часть не имеет секретных данных, поэтому его сохраняют в LocalStorage.

Comment: да,я тоже думаю, что локалСтораж может быть как раз то, что нужно, потому что там ну как бы большие данные. У меня вопрос, если вы уже делали, как происходит микс, то есть куки для чего то там и сейчас внедрить локалСтораж, такое как происходит?  и второй вопрос у меня куки через СиШарп класс создаются, а есть ли пример для локал стораж ?

Comment: микс никак не происходит, используйте разные стораджи в разных местах и всё. Посмотрите готовые либы, https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage или https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazor.LocalStorage

Comment: а что это значит *используйте бэк-энд приложения* ? вы проект когда на блазор делали, аспНет добавляли (server)

Comment: его же, только для веб Ассебмли https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazor.LocalStorage.WebAssembly/7.0.3#show-readme-container

Comment: да для нового проекта можете использовать AspNet.Core как бэкэнд - это очень удобно, а данные можете хранить в SQL SERVER EXPRESS, или PostgreSql, или Mongo DB или ещё где-то.

Comment: *...а данные можете хранить...* настройки, или о каких данных речь?

Comment: настройки, список пользователей и любые другие данные, когда они у вас появятся. Почти всё, что вы хотите сохранить, должно быть сохранено в БД на бэке. Представьте что у пользователя есть ноутбук, ПК, планшет и телефон. Вот что должно быть разным в локал сторадж, а что одинаковым - в БД.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146551/discussion-between-dev18-and-4per).

Comment: а вы использовали IndexedDb ? https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet6/indexeddb-storage-749869

Comment: я - нет. Как понимаю в нём есть смысл только если нужны web-worker-ы. Я не в курсе может ли Blazor wasm в воркеры.  И если и есть, то нельзя ли там использовать что-то более blazor-ное.

Comment: https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet7/indexeddb-storage-261461 по-моему это некая альтернатива базы данных, я попробовала использовать и на самом деле сохраняет базу клиентов, то есть те же настройки. У меня была загвоздка как Id auto-increment добавить. Я подумала вы говорили, что проект на Блазор ставили, может знаете знакомы. Ок. Спасибо

Comment: да не может это быть альтернативой, если Вашему приложению почему-то достаточно сохранять данные в одном конкретном браузере на одном устройстве, то ок. Но такое бывает редко. Если у вас есть регистрация пользователей,, вам уже априори нужна база на бэке.

Comment: Конечно есть база на беке, и через апи, юзеры подключаются и там уже вторая аутентификация. Мой случай еще одна база данных клиентов с настройками. Потому как вот буквально вчера я пыталась подключиться и создать базу на sql, и мне выпала ошибка "платформа не поддерживает", то есть wasm и server блазоры они в этом и отличаются. У нас коллега сделал базу данных на sql и так подключает их настройки, вчера я пыталась повторить его действия, и сюрприз блазор просто не поддерживает это,

Comment: конечно всегда можно найти решение https://www.prowaretech.com/articles/current/blazor/wasm/create-ms-sql-db-with-entity-framework#

Comment: между базой и blazor wasm должен быть rest api или его аналог.

Comment: я как бы не то что дублирую, но хочу создать новое хранилище для пользователей помимо той базы, где хранятся их логин, пароль.....просто пользователи еще должны много чего сохранять, а менять основную таблицу в беке, мне пока нет необходимости

Comment: да, конечно есть сервисАпи аналог рестАпи

Comment: а вы блазор на ассембли или сервис делали ?

Comment: ` еще должны много чего сохранять`
и им нормально, что они потеряют это "много чего" вместе с браузером? и то что оно хранится будет не конфенденциально?

Comment: как говорит их док, эта "база данных " не доступна из других ссылок, то есть маилРу не может видеть базу Яндекс к примеру. а вот как выглядит https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg2wk.png приблизительно база

Comment: там в основном настройки, и тот самый Айди....потому как вот вы мне показали как в локал стораж сохранять, я смогла, сохранила порядок колонок...НО нужен айди, чтоб КАЖДЫЙ пользователь имел свой порядок....итп

Comment: а потеряют они только если сотрут базу....или к примеру почистят кеш

Comment: так, заново сохранят, они же понимают, что при первом подключении все "новое", а чтоб ну поменять тему, цвет, порядок.....речь об этом

Comment: тему, цвет, порядок - да это нормально.